# Get labels for horizontal bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to plot a few horizontal bar chart, in a for loop. For each of my bars, I want to add a label to the top to show the count (exactly what the x_labels are)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in my_list:
    sns.set_palette("husl")
    ax = sns.barplot(x=data.sort_values(ascending = False), y=data.sort_values(ascending = False).index)
    ax.set_xlabel('number of clicks')

    # for each of the bars, try to get a label
    rects = ax.patches
    for rect in rects:
        y_value = rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2
        x_value = rect.get_height()
        label = "{:.1f}".format(x_value)
        plt.annotate(
        label,                     
        (x_value, y_value))             

   plt.show()
```

I got all my bar plots, but the labels are out of place and are not calculated right:

[image]

[image]

i am referencing this stackoverflow post: [Adding value labels on a matplotlib bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28931224/adding-value-labels-on-a-matplotlib-bar-chart)

Comment: You're mixing up width and height.

Comment: thats what i thought, but when i switch it, the labels just get jumbled up in another direction.

Comment: You may of course decide to provide a [mcve], such that I can provide a correct solution, else you need to figure out the correct correspondence between *x - horizontal - width* and *y - vertical - height* yourself.